# Woocommerce show shipping methods in checkout page?

Tags: php, wordpress, e-commerce, woocommerce

I am using  [woocommerce plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/) for wordpress. Everything in woocommerce is fine. Only in one thing where I am totally strucked. In checkout page I want to show all the shipping methods in list format. Here with I have attached the screenshot for the shipping method that I want. I have gone through many settings but I am not getting the result. So any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

[image: woocommerce plugin]

Answer (score 0):

In your wordpress Backend Go to

> WooCommerce -> Settings -> Shipping

You will see list of all shipping methods like this
[image]

Activte and configured all shipping methods, And for for some shipping methods, Your product must have dimensions like "Weight,Length,Width,Height" In order to calculate shipping charge.

Hope, It will help you!

Comment: All the shipping methods to be shown in checkout page(frontend not backend)?

Comment: Agree, But for that, you will have to activate it in Back end first

Comment: I am sure, You are missing somethings - Just refere this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=Is5VjRAadSA#at=715

And make sure about all configuration

Comment: So, Are you succeeded  with youtube tutorial?

Comment: For me the problem was in the products that hadnt its dimensions set. Just set dimensions and be happy

Answer (score 0):

i tried some more setting on "shipping options' page and works for me finally.

- Enable the shipping calculator on the cart page > disable
- Hide shipping costs until an address is entered > disable
- most important, make sure u test ur cart/ checkout page on different computer (guest)

Answer (score 0):

You first have to create Shipping zones and add shipping method specific to those zones. Now as soon as you enter the address on the checkout page, WooCommerce searches for that address in all the zones and if matched display all the shipping assigned to that zone.

Answer (score 0):

This Worked for me:

Under WooCommerce/Settings/Shipping zones clear the 'Zone regions' then under shipping options/ Calculations uncheck both:

1. "Enable the shipping calculator on the cart page"
           and
2. "Hide shipping costs until an address is entered"

The plugin
"Shipping Method Display Style for WooCommerce" by "Thedotstore" may be handy.